# how can i echo contents of 2 associative arrays into one table?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

this is my code snippets and the result is not the thing that i want.I have 2 associative arrays and want to echo their contents into one table like before the  html  tag.how can i do that?

```
    team A:                      team B:
    player_one                   player_five
    player_two                   player_six
    player_three                 player_seven
    player_four                  player_eight



<html>
<head>

<title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table widht='100%' border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>team A</td>
        <td>team B</td>

    </tr>

<?php

$team_a=array("goalkeeper"=>"player_one","defender"=>"player_two","midfielder"=>"player_three","forward"=>"player_four");
$team_b=array("goalkeeper"=>"player_five","defender"=>"player_six","midfielder"=>"player_seven","forward"=>"player_eight");



foreach($team_a as $index1 => $value1 ){

foreach($team_b as $index2 => $value2 )
 echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$value1</td>
                <td>$value2</td>

            </tr>
            ";
            }

?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could combine the arrays first and line them up accordingly, them print them:

```
<?php

$team_a=array("goalkeeper"=>"player_one","defender"=>"player_two","midfielder"=>"player_three","forward"=>"player_four");
$team_b=array("goalkeeper"=>"player_five","defender"=>"player_six","midfielder"=>"player_seven","forward"=>"player_eight");

$teams = array();
$keys = array_keys($team_a);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $teams[$key] = array($team_a[$key], $team_b[$key]);
}
?>
<table widht='100%' border="1">
<tr>
    <td>team A</td>
    <td>team B</td>
</tr>
<?php foreach($teams as $players): ?>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach($players as $player): ?><td><?php echo $player; ?></td><?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

[Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/R4mvDf)

Or if you do not want the original arrays touched or using a new array, then just loop them accordingly:

```
<?php

$team_a=array("goalkeeper"=>"player_one","defender"=>"player_two","midfielder"=>"player_three","forward"=>"player_four");
$team_b=array("goalkeeper"=>"player_five","defender"=>"player_six","midfielder"=>"player_seven","forward"=>"player_eight");

?>
<table widht='100%' border="1">
<tr>
    <td>team A</td>
    <td>team B</td>
</tr>
<?php foreach($team_a as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value; ?></td><td><?php echo $team_b[$key]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// drop indexes because you don't use them anyway
$a = array_values($team_a);
$b = array_values($team_b);

// process arrays
max = max(count($a), count($b));
for ($i=0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td>' . (isset($a[$i] ? $a[$i] : '-')) . '</td>
        <td>' . (isset($b[$i] ? $b[$i] : '-')) . '</td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
```